# Trouble with gitlab ssh-key

Tags: ssh, gitlab

In my laptop, I've added SSH-Key for GitHub, and it work nice. Now I am going to use GitLab. The first step is add SSH-Key to clone private repo. When I added SSH-Key for gitlab and verified it, there is a problem here.

[image]

I've add in my hosts file too:

[image]

When I try to clone from gitlab, it has error.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you're starting a SSH-Agent in **MinGW** in order to access to GitLab, but afterwards you're using **PowerShell** in order to try to clone the aimed repository.

First of all, have you checked that you have loaded the correct agent in `SSH_AUTH_SOCK`? Because it seems to me that you don't have any `ssh-agent` in PowerShell so that's what is giving you errors.

In order to start a `ssh-agent` in **PowerShell**, you'd need to do it as a service, so you could just do

```
PS> Start-Service ssh-agent
```

or if you want the `ssh-agent` to start with Windows, you could run (from an elevated PS prompt):

```
PS> Set-Service ssh-agent -StartupType Automatic
```

Afterwards you just need to add your ssh key once, but to that agent:

```
PS> ssh-add "E:\SSH key\Gitlab\gitlab"
```

### Error with Permissions with SSH-Key

If you have an error with permissions with your SSH Private-Key, you should run the following commands in an elevated prompt PowerShell:

```
icacls.exe "E:\SSH key\Gitlab\gitlab" /reset
icacls.exe "E:\SSH key\Gitlab\gitlab" /GRANT:R "$($env:USERNAME):(R)"
icacls.exe "E:\SSH key\Gitlab\gitlab" /inheritance:r
```

This will just give read access to the current user to the key.

Comment: Oh no, it still error with GitLab. But Github is still work :(((

Comment: Can you verify that you have access to that repository using that concrete SSH Key? What does it say when you try to perform SSH to `gitlab.com` from PowerShell?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16H6486fBzGyCycM1B1MhlPVJh0i5q6Fa/view?usp=sharing here is the result guys

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yvS9dUsItPgiGgij3mpW98ix2_dK2MR1/view?usp=sharing and result when I clone

Comment: Well, it's clearly telling you that you have a problem with the permissions of the private-key and that due to that it will ignore it. Try to set the permissions properly (I'll update my answer)

Comment: :(( still don't work guys

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pL41mi_y_Cp6XaSdKBdifKZ7yFBqvSbw/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cN1uycaWjDzIsJlPv-Y8MZzJGkgyEYeo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Don't change anything from the commands I provided you. `$env:USERNAME` already gets your real username, no need to modify it as you make in the attached screenshot. Also, you have to modify the permissions BEFORE you perform the SSH-related commands.

Comment: Hey guys, I redo the command, but still error.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ptD7DQV7UpH8o28x_ifAfu_c2VWBBHif/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PwCWJRFIpMvWsT3dOjk5p_07drY1If-f/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I just told you that you have to do it BEFORE the SSH-related commands... You need to re import the private key, since the first time was ignored due to the permissions problem you were facing.

Comment: I'm using the same gmail on GitHub and GitLab, does it have some effect guys ?

Comment: What? No, that doesn't matter at all.

Comment: Hey guys, I've solved the problem. I just change the config file in "C:\User\<Your accound>\.ssh\config" and clone. It works for me. Sorry for my bad config. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/16czY1XJDFfsbOvHsPm7XFTAOqwj5PB--/view?usp=sharing